# Convert Salesforce Managed Package into a paid App

Tags: salesforce1-app

We recently uploaded a Managed Package to the AppExchange. We want to make that App payable but still we haven't configured yet the Checkout neither any alternative way, since we have a couple of questions.

1. Some customers already have the package installed (before we put it in the AppExchange). Currently, they have valid license, but if we introduced Checkout, would they need to pay if they upgrade the APP? We want them to continue using it for free
2. By the moment we have active the option "Paid without Checkout" in the listing. However we haven't implemented anything to follow the orders or do the payment yet, so clients can install it directly. Would we need to make a payment to Salesforce for every installation?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Some customers already have the package installed (before we put it in the AppExchange). Currently, they have valid license, but if we introduced Checkout, would they need to pay if they upgrade the APP? We want them to continue using it for free

You are allowed to honor your existing agreements. You can configure how many Licenses they have via the Licence Management App (LMA). The price listed on the AppExchange is kind of a MSRP (Suggested Retail Price). What you actually charge is up to you.

> By the moment we have active the option "Paid without Checkout" in the listing. However we haven't implemented anything to follow the orders or do the payment yet, so clients can install it directly. Would we need to make a payment to Salesforce for every installation?

As an ISV, you are required to make a percent-based payment in exchange for being an ISV partner. This is somewhere between 15 to 25%. If you give away complimentary licenses, you don't pay for those (15% of 0 is 0). You pay only for paid licenses.